# rosmak error - ivcon: Command not found

Tags: ros, buiding-errors, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all!

I can't  compiling package katana_description. I have this error:

```
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linestana_description: 3.5 sec ] [ 1 Active 42/43 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/max/hydro_ws/devel;/opt/ros/hydro
  -- This workspace overlays: /home/max/hydro_ws/devel;/opt/ros/hydro
  -- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
  -- Using Debian Python package layout
  -- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
  -- Skip enable_testing() for dry packages
  -- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/max/hydro_ros_ws/katana_driver/katana_description/build/test_results
  -- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
  -- catkin 0.5.81
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/hydro/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/hydro/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/hydro/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  CMake Warning:
    Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
  
      CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
  
  
  -- Build files have been written to: /home/max/hydro_ros_ws/katana_driver/katana_description/build
  cd build && make -j2 -l2
  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/max/hydro_ros_ws/katana_driver/katana_description/build'
  make[2]: Entering directory `/home/max/hydro_ros_ws/katana_driver/katana_description/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/max/hydro_ros_ws/katana_driver/katana_description/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/max/hydro_ros_ws/katana_driver/katana_description/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/max/hydro_ros_ws/katana_driver/katana_description/build'
  [  3%] [  3%] Generating ../meshes/katana/convex/katana_motor2_lift_link.obj
  Generating ../meshes/katana/convex/katana_gripper_l_finger.obj
  make[3]: ivcon: Command not found
  make[3]: ivcon: Command not found
  make[3]: *** [../meshes/katana/convex/katana_gripper_l_finger.obj] Error 127
  make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  make[3]: *** [../meshes/katana/convex/katana_motor2_lift_link.obj] Error 127
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/max/hydro_ros_ws/katana_driver/katana_description/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/media_files.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/max/hydro_ros_ws/katana_driver/katana_description/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/max/hydro_ros_ws/katana_driver/katana_description/build'
```

I already install package invoc from https://github.com/ros/ivcon , but it can't halpe me. (ubuntu 12.04, hydro)
How I can fix it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/137581/rosmak-error---ivcon:-command-not-found/) by [seredin](https://answers.ros.org/users/8936/seredin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2014-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@iandanforth's answer should work, but you don't even need to build from source. Just do:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-ivcon ros-hydro-convex-decomposition
```

After that, the necessary binaries will be located in `/opt/ros/hydro/bin`, so if you've sourced setup.bash, they should be on your `$PATH`.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2015-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1